# all possible keys of an union type

Tags: typescript

I want to get all available keys of an union type.

```
interface Foo {
  foo: string;
}

interface Bar {
   bar: string;
}

type Batz = Foo | Bar;

type AvailableKeys = keyof Batz;
```

I want to have `'foo' | 'bar'` as result of `AvailableKeys` but it is `never` (as alternative I could do `keyof (Foo & Bar)`, what produces exact the required type but I want to avoid to repeat the Types).

I found already the issue [`keyof` union type should produce union of keys](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12948) at github. I understand the answer, that `keyof UnionType` should not produce all possible keys.

So my question is: Is there an other way to get the list of all possible keys (it is ok if the verison 2.8 of tsc is required)?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

This can be done in typescript 2.8 and later using conditional types. Conditional types iterate over types in a union, union-ing the result:

```
type Batz = Foo | Bar;

type KeysOfUnion<T> = T extends T ? keyof T: never;
// AvailableKeys will basically be keyof Foo | keyof Bar 
// so it will be  "foo" | "bar"
type AvailableKeys = KeysOfUnion<Batz>;
```

The reason a simple `keyof Union` does not work is because `keyof` always returns the accessible keys of a type, in the case of a union that will only be the common keys. The conditional type in `KeysOfUnion` will actually take each member of the union and get its keys so the result will be a union of `keyof` applied to each member in the union.

Comment: this is awesome - can you explain the difference between KeysOfUnion type and a simple `keyof T` type? the former returns the correct union of the keys, the latter an intersection (which is not useful)

Comment: @dmwong2268 added a bit more of an explanation let me know if it's clear

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Your solution works, but your explanation doesn't seem to explain anything, just re-states the behavior. I found a discussion on gitter in which you're pointing to the right place where it's explained, so let me add it here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types

Comment: Great answer!
I also found that you have to use generics, otherwise it won't work.

type allBatzKeys = KeysOfUnion<Batz> // "foo"|"bar"   
type alternativeAllBatzKeys = Batz extends any ? keyof Batz: never;  // never

Comment: To elaborate on the explanation a little more - this works due to the _distributive conditionals_ linked by @MártonSári above, in which conditional clauses on a union type are automatically turned into unions of conditionals.  Crucially, the statement `T extends T` is ALWAYS TRUE, so this type will turn T into a union of conditionals all of which will follow the true branch.  It's basically a bit of a hack, because we're not really doing anything conditional at all.

Comment: Amazing. Feel like this should be a generally available utility type

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a union type, you need an intersection type:

```
type Batz = Foo & Bar;
```

I agree that their naming can sometimes be confusing.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I really meant the union type. I want to get all possible keys of an union type (yes of Foo or Bar) so that I can do a exhaustive check.

Comment: @Xenya Would you please provide a case in which `type Batz = Foo & Bar;` doesn't work for getting the keys? In the above case, `Batz` is `'foo' | 'bar'` as expected.

Comment: you're right, for getting the key it works. But I have already the type `type Batz = Foo | Bar;`. I want to avoid to rewrite the type with `&`.