# How to achieve structural typesafety when target is given in curried function

Tags: typescript

I am trying to achieve structural typesafety with a curried function where the first argument is the key of an object and the return curry function it's argument takes the target (object).

I have prepared a fully working playground, as it much easier to explain there:
[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEElQCwQwNwKahqAtjADqA9gM1AEoIDO2ArgE4DGJoA7lAhUgC6OgDWCAnscs6AQBHMjAA2oFtkntmpSjVABLFgHI+LbhgQBYAFD7N2wiXLVaAXlABvfaFBliTAFw2795QBNXxFhSUAdgDm7vZGCK6qjkyqocgsfkoARmQsJK62eh4eATCoEaC+-sFx9jBBBQFkqElMpaBiML4A+rn5PoklWR4Avu49ADTuIA4BVNio+QEsMkp8TlQsStgBktJJzDAcoLhkY0sro55MAQgwbPrDYA5OFEEU5BgZVx5K3oWdId0jYVoFUbd7o9Yt9rvFEik0sRnqDsmhsL4mO8ioEvvYfh4gWQnh9imjQBi+rCiUTDH8TPJzAAVP58Kxcbh4ClmGjEfQjaIUAA+nKxGEuenCoAAqrcAIIJfyQyycHhMoiU1kAbQBMQAuirzhDUiRVGr2WA2ggueVjY0WkaBbt9stVuMAkUYIEADzuKmCAAeaQCnj41kkf1cCpZCBp2j4g3cYs93t9ssZ+GDChISqpKvCeo1qi1Up1xD1+gAfKAABQ55I61xigCUbm6zBYlFWJbkIdcVNrFmLmX6+lJehG4D4KlAGARxGSYlY0gqM3CxBguAQmh22AoMiQ5el-CC1QQ01ABvojFWreTO73B9gfFq+9AQSUiACAwaSi4q7EYmwdFRnryGCnAB+fR7V8UA5DIMQZisUC-CdAIS1UI1VGrEt-XCSJOVUUAemrAUhTFT8JW1KFQHpOVE1MZNiCVJNqVpLMtzzAsBzAWpxnyPhTkQCgX0gJpiD3WZhz4BhzmUPhYAwbQAl-QIN1AWCKHgnY9kWW1QEhY9uEUmADxHQIl3XNgkDomgwwQQCgA)

```
// I have a map of Resources where the keys are equal to the resource it's type

type Resources = {
  user: {
    id: string
    type: 'user'
    attributes: {
      name: string
      age: number
      last_name: string
    }
  },
  // uncomment this section to break function underneath

  //  usergroup: {
  //   id: string
  //   type: 'usergroup'
  //   attributes: {
  //     mosterd: string
  //     group: string
  //   }
  // }
}

type ResourceTypes = keyof Resources
// user|usergroup

type UserAttributes = keyof Resources['user']['attributes']
// name|age|last_name

function constrain<
  T extends { type: ResourceTypes },
  A extends keyof Resources[T['type']]['attributes']
> (attribute: A) {
  return (resource: T) => {

  }
}

// Is it possible to get typesafety for the attribute argument 
// when resource argument has been given, like following example?
const result = constrain('name')({ type: 'user' })

type AllAttributes = keyof Resources[ResourceTypes]['attributes']
// becomes never, I assume this is what is happening in the constrain function but why cant it infer the ResourceType?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to somewhat mysterious behavior of TypeScript, you'll have to construct a type for getting all keys of a union, using [the answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49402091).

EDIT: I've updated the generic constraints for the function so that the inner key (which is of `AllAttributes` type) matches the resource type.

```js
type KeysOfUnion<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type NoKeys = keyof ({ a: 1 } | { b: 2 }); // never
type AllKeys = KeysOfUnion<{ a: 1 } | { b: 2 }>; // 'a' | 'b'

type AllAttributes = KeysOfUnion<Resources[ResourceTypes]['attributes']>;
// will now be 'name' | 'age' | 'last_name' | 'mosterd' | 'group'

function constrain<
  A extends KeysOfUnion<Resources[keyof Resources]['attributes']>,
  T extends {
    [x in keyof Resources]: Resources[x]['attributes'] extends {
      [y in A]: unknown;
    }
      ? x
      : never;
  }[keyof Resources]
>(attribute: A) {
  return (resource: { type: T }) => {};
}

constrain('name')({ type: 'user' }); // OK
constrain('name')({ type: 'usergroup' }); // error
constrain('group')({ type: 'usergroup' }); // OK
constrain('group')({ type: 'user' }); // error
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Although the function now doesnt give an error, it's not a solution as it will now also accept properties for types that do not have that property. eg. You can now add usergroup resource properties to user resource...

Comment: I've edited the answer. Please check if my updated solution works for you.

Comment: Yes, it does. thats quite clever, you've basically inversed the type checking flow. Very insightful. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `UnionToIntersection<U>` ([credits to jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/637367)) and define your function as

```
function constrain<
  A extends keyof UnionToIntersection<Resources[keyof Resources]['attributes']>,
  T extends Extract<Resources[keyof Resources], { attributes: Record<A, any> }>,
  >(attribute: A) {
  return (resource: { type: T['type'] }) => {

  }
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=43&ssc=1&pln=35&pc=1#code/PTAEElQCwQwNwKahqAtjADqA9gM1AEoIDO2ArgE4DGJoA7lAhUgC6OgDWCAnscs6AQBHMjAA2oFtkntmpSjVABLFgHI+LbhgQBYAFD7N2wiXLVaAXlABvfaFBliTAFw2795QBNXxFhSUAdgDm7vZGCK6qjkyqocgsfkoARmQsJK62eh4eATCoEaC+-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-G7AJFVUatVDNRVrBw7RImuVRiLNTlCXjYzExLcF5WHFcs0XZ9SXJDcRJ3ctpNqcZ8j4B0mHfSAmmICTZjovgGHOZQ+FgDBtH5YJlFWNgkDcy9Ah2PZFjbMEZL1KgdRmeifT9VraTXMltH1IA)

Comment: Nice use of `Extract<>` utility type!