# Key of union type as function argument

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to implement a UI where a client can search using either of many attributes. AFAIK this could be achieved with union types. So far my implementation looks like this

```js
interface GivenNameSearchTerm {
    readonly givenName: string;
}

interface FamilyNameSearchTerm {
    readonly familyName: string;
}

type SearchTerm = GivenNameSearchTerm | FamilyNameSearchTerm;

const search = (input: SearchTerm): Results[] => {
  // do stuff
}
```

Now, I want to call the `search` function by allowing user to select both which attribute to search by and its value.

According to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49402091/4526329), narrowing the possible keys can be done with conditional types

```js
type SearchInput<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;

const test = (key: SearchInput<SearchTerm>, value: string) => {
    search({ [key]: value });
}
```

This approach lets me narrow the values `key` can have, allowing only `givenName` or `familyName`, but TypeScript shows this error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type  { [x: string]: string; }  is not assignable to parameter of type  SearchTerm 
Property  familyName  is missing in type  { [x: string]: string; }  but required in type  FamilyNameSearchTerm
```

If I hardcode the key everything works, but user should be able to choose it. Any ideas?

I checked the documentation on [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) but in this case I don't need to narrow the type, just accept any of the union ones. Though by narrowing the type there are no errors but this leads to duplicate code:

```js
const test = (key: SearchInput<SearchTerm>, value: string) => {
  switch (key) {
    case 'givenName':
      search({ [key]: value });
      break;
    case 'familyName':
      search({ [key]: value });
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a known issue at [ms/TS#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) where you get an index signature you don't want; my workaround is usually [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948#issuecomment-1333159066) as shown [in this version of your code](https://tsplay.dev/wQq11w).  See the linked q/a for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the type using:

`search({ [key]: value } as {[key in typeof key]: typeof value});`

```
interface GivenNameSearchTerm {
    readonly givenName: string;
}

interface FamilyNameSearchTerm {
    readonly familyName: string;
}

type SearchTerm = GivenNameSearchTerm | FamilyNameSearchTerm;

const search = (input: SearchTerm): Results[] => {
// do stuff
return "";
}

type SearchInput<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;

const test = (key: SearchInput<SearchTerm>, value: string) => {
    search({ [key]: value } as {[key in typeof key]: typeof value});
}

test("inValid", "asd"); // TS error: Argument of type '"inValid"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"givenName" | "familyName"'.
test("givenName", "asd");  // Pass
```